# Return keys that have value with the given phrase (array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord, discord.js

I have problem with JavaScript array. I am trying to create a function that, according to a particular arg, returns keys with a value that has that arg.

The code I tried:

```js
    for(let i in client.commands.size) {
        let filteredCommands = client.commands.filter(cmd => cmd[i].help.cmdCategory = arg).map(c => c.name)
        console.log(filteredCommands)
        embed.addField(`${filteredCommands.help.name}`, `**Description:** ${filteredCommands.help.desc}\n**Usage:** \`${client.prefix}${filteredCommands.help.usage}\`\n**Exxample Usage:** ${filteredCommands.help.exampleUsage}`, false)
    }
```

`client.commands` it's a array who key is name of command, and value in command key (example. `ping`) named `cmdCategory` is in `help` subkey and need value same in argument and next return keys which meet this condition. (for example: if key value `cmdCategory` have value `fun`, then return keys who meet this criteria. Any ideas for here? Thanks anyway.

Comment: `cmd[i].help.cmdCategory = arg` <= single `=` is assignment, not equality.  Probably a typo problem.

Comment: Though `filteredCommands` is going to be an array in any case.  So `filteredCommands.help` is an obvious code smell

Answer (score 0):

If your object client looks like this example then you can try it

```js
let arg = 'sh'

let client = {
 commands: [
   [
     {
       help: {
          cmdCategory: 'bash',
          name: 'some bash name',
          desc: 'description for bash'
        }
      }, 
     {
       help: {
          cmdCategory: 'sh',
          name: 'some sh name',
          desc: 'description for sh'
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}

// reduce from [[{}, {}]] to [{},{}]
let commands = client.commands.reduce((prev, next) => {
 return prev.concat(next)
})

let filteredCommands = commands.filter(command => command.help.cmdCategory === arg)
console.log(filteredCommands)

filteredCommands.forEach(cmd => {
/* embed.addField(`${cmd.help.name}`, `**Description:** ${cmd.help.desc}\n**Usage:** \`${client.prefix}${cmd.help.usage}\`\n**Exxample Usage:** ${cmd.help.exampleUsage}`, false) */
})

// OR you can do this:
filteredCommands = []

client.commands.forEach(cmd => {
    cmd.forEach(item => {
        if (item.help.cmdCategory === arg) {
                filteredCommands.push(item)
            }
        })
})

console.log(filteredCommands)
```